# Value of variable changes.

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

I'm starting to learn C programming and am having an issue with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float jobPrice (int numberOfPages, float pricePerSheet, float pricePerPlate, int numberOfCopies)
{
    return (((pricePerPlate * numberOfPages) + ((numberOfPages/2)*numberOfCopies*pricePerSheet) + (numberOfCopies*2)) * 1.175f);
}


float colourPrinting (int numberOfPages, int numberOfCopies)
{
    return jobPrice(numberOfPages, 0.04f, 28.00f, numberOfCopies);
}

int main ()
{
    printf("%f\n", colourPrinting(32, 1000));
    return 0;
}
```

The value that should be printed is 4154.8 but my program is printing 4154.799805. I've debugged the code and it seems that when calling jobPrice with the pricePerSheet parameter of 0.04f, it's changing to 0.0399999991.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `double` instead of `float`.  A `float` provides at most 7 significant decimal digits, and your printing format is trying to extract 10, which leads to garbage.  Or print just 2 decimal places; that will give you the answer with 6 significant figures.

See ['What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic'](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Floating point numbers are not represented exactly, but rather by approximation.

`0.0399999991` is your system's representation of `0.04f`

You can read more on this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic is not precise; there is no guarantee that if you start with one decimal you'll keep one decimal, even if you only do operations that if you did on paper would yield the same number of decimals. If you want to maintain a certain number of decimals (particularly when working with money), use integers and convert to decimal when you need to (if you're working with dollars, you can think of this as cents).